# Serializar objeto composto em um único json

Tags: c#, json, serialização, newtonsoft

Com o Newtonsoft.Json, para o objeto seguinte:

```
  public class Person
  {    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GeneralText { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
  }

  public class Address
  {
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Neighborhood { get; set; }
  }
```

Eu obtenho o seguinte json:

```
{
  "Name": "TEST",
  "GeneralText": "TEST",
  "Address": {
    "Street": "TEST",
    "Neighborhood": "TEST"
  }
}
```

Porém, preciso, com esta mesma estrutura de objeto, de um json no seguinte formato:

```
{
  "Name": "TEST",
  "GeneralText": "TEST",
  "Street": "TEST",
  "Neighborhood": "TEST"
}
```

Ou seja, preciso que a classe `Adress` não seja agrupada, mas que suas propriedades apenas apareçam. Como posso fazer isso?

**Edit 1:**
Eu gostaria de criar uma classe genérica, como:

```
public class DefaultApiReturn<T>
{
    public T RetObject { get; set; }
}
```

Todos os meus retornos de API teriam essa classe com o tipo do meu retorno, porém não seria agrupado por ela no retorno do Json, ela seria para concentrar algumas coisas a serem executadas em todas as serializações, ou outras coisas. Poderia fazer ela herdar de alguma classe que configurasse coisas da minha API sem afetar a modelagem do meu objeto.

Portanto, ao invés de ficar:

```
{
  "RetObject ": {
    "Property1": "TEST",
    "Property2": "TEST"
  }
}
```

Gostaria que ficasse

```
{
    "Property1": "TEST",
    "Property2": "TEST"
}
```

Comment: O retorno do do tipo `T` ainda refletiria a estrutura do objeto original com sua hierarquia... porém com o prefíxo RetObject, seu Json firacaria `{ "RetObject": {...}}`

Comment: A classe "Person" que usei foi mais um exemplo de o que eu gostaria que fizesse. A hierarquia e composição do objeto T pode manter, eu só gostaria de "ocultar" a classe genérica. De que, ao serializar esta classe, serializasse apenas suas propriedades, não agrupando elas.

Comment: Pois é, eu queria remover esse "RetObject", deixar as propriedades na raiz do json.

Comment: Para deixar tudo no "mesmo  nível" não tem mágica, você precisará criar um novo objeto para isso. Pode fazer manualmente para cada tipo de retorno ou utilizar reflection que só vai aumentar a complexidade e prejudicar a performance. Você ainda não informou a razão  desse requisito, qual é o problema de manter a estrutura do objeto no json?

Comment: A empresa que trabalho demanda que se utilize um framework local para APIs. Entretanto, este framework pede que as classes da API herdem de determinada classe deles e isso atrapalha minha modelagem dos objetos. A serialização deles é realizada com o newtonsoft e se eu conseguisse com alguma propriedade dele resolver esse problema, criaria uma classe genérica como mostrei e sempre retornaria ela, e manteria minha modelagem independente do framework.

Comment: @Salatiel, pelo que entendi você gostaria dinamizar o uso framework da empresa porém pelo que entendo genéricos são serializados como `object`. O que dá para fazer desserializar um objeto qualquer dentro dum tipo `dynamic` porém, pela minha experiência em empresas, o pessoal do controle não deixa passar código com dados tipificados como dynamic. Não sei se é seu caso, mas empresas investem muito capital para se adequarem a frameworks de tipificação, acho que é ISO 42010(não tenho certeza), e se você aparece com um modelo de tipificação dinâmica o caras vetam sem dar explicação.

Comment: Realmente, utilizar dynamic não seria o melhor. Entretanto, tenho bastante contato com os devs do framework, e estou tentando conseguir que eles mudem isso, reduzindo o acoplamento. Porém ainda não é garantido que isso vai acontecer e já queria ter uma forma de resolver o acoplamento que isso tem criado nos meus códigos.

Comment: Não vejo necessidade de mudar o framework... esses modelos são os contratos do serviço, você deve respeitá-los do seu lado... Se o serviço existe determinado modelo, você deve alterar sua estrutura com para atender esses requisitos. Se você não deseja alterar a sua camada de dados e entidades, utilize DTOs, ViewModels e etc para atendê-los.

Comment: Uma alternativa que pensei durante o almoço foi dentro da sua camada trabalhar com um modelo de dados em XML e antes de transmitir a informação processa-la com um XSLT gerando o formato requisitado pelo framework.

Comment: Talvez.. Vou dar mais uma testada aqui pra ver se consigo algo.

Answer (score 3):

Basta você montar um novo objeto com a estrutura desejada para a serialização.

```
var person = new Person
{
    Name = "Leandro",
    GeneralText = "teste",
    Address = new Address
    {
        Street = "Visconde de Nácar",
        Neighborhood = "Centro"
    }
};

var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    person.Name,
    person.GeneralText,
    person.Address.Street,
    person.Address.Neighborhood
});
```

**Resultado:**

```
{
  "Name":"Leandro",
  "GeneralText":"teste",
  "Street":"Visconde de Nácar",
  "Neighborhood":"Centro"
}
```

Comment: Mas isso teria que ser específico para cada um. Vou colocar um edit ali pra explicar melhor o que eu preciso.

Comment: Você pode até utilizar reflection para isso, mas é uma carga desnecessária e ainda terá de tomar cuidado com propriedades repetidas... A minha pergunta é por quê você precisa desse objeto planificado?

Comment: Coloquei um edit ali tentando explicar melhor o por quê.